# Someone have stole my BTC

Tags: transactions, wallet, theft, copay

Someone have stole my BTC  is anyway to recover my BTC amount.
I use Copay wallet and someone from Russia has loged in my account and transfered to other account all my BTC.

Is anyway to recover my BTC ?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately not...you can look up your bitcoin address on the blockchain explorer and see the transaction and the address that received your bitcoins .How do you know it was someone from Russia?Is it someone you know?